# CMake: run command before all dependencies of target

Tags: cmake

Suppose I have following project structure:

```
my_project_dir
   libs/
      third-party-lib/
         configure.sh
         CMakeLists.txt
   CMakeLists.txt
```

my_project/libs/third-party-lib/CMakeLists.txt

```
...
add_library(lib_inner)
add_library(lib)
target_link_libraries(lib PRIVATE lib_inner)
...
```

my_project_dir/CMakeLists.txt

```
add_executable(my_exe)
add_custom_target(configure_third_party_lib ALL 
    COMMAND 
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/libs/third-party-lib/config.sh
)
add_dependencies(lib configure_third_party_lib)
target_link_libraries(my_exe PRIVATE lib)
```

Does CMake guarantee the next build order?

1. configure_third_party_lib
2. lib_inner
3. lib
4. my_exe

Or this order is possible:

1. **lib_inner**
2. **configure_third_party_lib**
3. lib
4. my_exe

?

[doc](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_dependencies.html) says that add_dependencies guarantees that **configure_third_party_lib** will run before **lib**, but I didn't find anything about **lib** dependencies.

Comment: Targets `lib_inner` and `configure_third_party_lib` are connected neither with `add_dependencies` nor with `target_link_libraries`, so these targets could be built in **any order**. Not sure why do you expect the opposite...

Comment: @Tsyvarev I want to run some configuration before lib will be built. The lib is third-party lib and I don't want to make any assumptions about it inner structure (for example, about lib_inner dependency). So, my question is how to run lib configuration before lib and it dependencies will be built.

Comment: "my question is how to run lib configuration before lib and it dependencies will be built." - So, effectively you ask how to make all targets in the specific directory (`libs/third-party-lib/` in your case) to depend on some target (`configure_third_party_lib`). There is no such way. Instead of putting your configuration code into the target, you may put it into `execute_process`, so it will be executed on configuration stage. Or you may use the external library via `ExternalProject_Add`, where you could add additional steps.

Comment: BTW, your tree structure contains the file `configure.sh`, but your custom target runs `config.sh`. So, what is the actual name of the file? If it is `configure.sh`, then it looks like a script which configures the project **instead** of CMake. Or it just calls `cmake`. It is unlikely that you need both to run `configure.sh` and to use CMake for build the external project.